# 17.04, can't detect HDMI monitor, ThinkPad P51

Tags: hdmi, thinkpad, 17.04

I installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my new ThinkPad P51 and installed Nvidia drivers in the Additional Drivers settings.

But it can't detect any HDMI displays, neither when connected directly to the laptop, nor when connected through the docking station.

```
$ inxi -SGx
System:    Host: sma-laptop Kernel: 4.10.0-21-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 6.3.0)
           Desktop: Gnome  (Gtk 3.22.11-0ubuntu3) Distro: Ubuntu 17.04
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 591b bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM206GLM [Quadro M2200 Mobile] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.3 drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 3840x2160@60.02hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Kabylake GT2 GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.3 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks =)

Comment: did you have any luck with this? I just purchased a P51 and plan on installing ubuntu so I am very curious.

Comment: No, I didn't. All I found out was that having 2 graphics cards confuses ubuntu, but not how to fix it. I guess you could try disabling the hardware somehow.

Comment: I have a Lenovo p51 with Debian Stretch (9), and am also having issues with the HDMI external display. I found that if I set Discrete Graphics (instead of Hybrid) in the BIOS, then the laptop booted using the external HDMI monitor. Yay! However, once the lid was closed and Debian went to sleep, I lost the screen again...

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue on my Lenovo P51 with Quadro M2200 graphics card. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. Here's how I fixed it:

1. Boot your laptop (not connected to HDMI) in Hybrid Graphics mode.
2. Install nvidia-prime.
3. Change settings in "PRIME Profiles" to "NVIDIA (Performance Mode)".
4. Logout to apply changes.
5. Connect HDMI.

It now displays in both screens.

Answer (score 0):

I have a P51, running Ubuntu 17.04, using dual monitor, it works fine as long as I use 4.10.0-21 kernel, anything above, doesn't.